# How to replace or edit the lookup parameter in a django rest framework Router?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have set up a Django Rest Framework `ModelViewSet` for a Product model. The Product has a `uuid4` primary key field. The API list views are working, but I can't access the detail views using the default router, I guess because the `uuid4` primary key doesn't fit the `pk` integer regex the router expects? The error is a `TypeError` in `python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py`:

> retrieve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

[From the router documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers), I believe I need a custom router, but I don't understand how to replace the `{lookup}` field from an integer pk regex to a uuid4 regex `(?P<uuid>[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12})`. I think the relevant part of the source code is [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L227).

My present url config is as follows:

```
from .views.API.product import ProductViewSet
from django.conf.urls import include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'product', ProductViewSet, base_name='product')
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^API/0.1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply update your code to something like this:

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'my_uuid_field'
```

`lookup_field` tells DRF to use this field instead of `pk` to get items